# running two nodejs apps in one docker image

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

how can i run two different nodejs apps in one docker image?
two different `CMD [ "node", "app.js"]` and `CMD [ "node", "otherapp.js"]` won't work, cause there can be only one `CMD` directive in *Dockerfile*.

Comment: You could wrap the start commands for both Node apps in a "start script" - see here a [Docker tutorial](http://ishlema.co.za/running-services-when-docker-container-starts/)  for this - I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: You are given the solution below, but why would you want it? What is the benefit of coupling the two in such a way?

Comment: I agree that most of the time you'd be better off running each app in its own image. In our case however there was no other way we could assure both apps would be running on one network. The story is too long to for a SO comment though. We hope to have them split one day.

Comment: its the way the app working today, so while dockerize it i stumbled to this problem. of course, later i will optimize it and run in two different containers, however for now i prefer to do it the old way

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend using [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) as the entrypoint process which will handle all your NodeJS applications within docker image. The advantage of this is that `pm2` can bahave as a proper process manager which is [essential in docker](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/). Other helpful features are load balancing, restarting applications which consume too much memory or just die for whatever reason, and log management.

Here's a `Dockerfile` I've been using for some time now:

```
#A lightweight node image
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6.5.0

#PM2 will be used as PID 1 process
RUN npm install -g pm2@1.1.3

# Copy package json files for services

COPY app1/package.json /var/www/app1/package.json
COPY app2/package.json /var/www/app2/package.json

# Set up working dir
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install packages
RUN npm config set loglevel warn \
# To mitigate issues with npm saturating the network interface we limit the number of concurrent connections
    && npm config set maxsockets 5 \
    && npm config set only production \
    && npm config set progress false \
    && cd ./app1 \
    && npm i \
    && cd ../app2 \
    && npm i


# Copy source files
COPY . ./

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 3001

# Start PM2 as PID 1 process
ENTRYPOINT ["pm2", "--no-daemon", "start"]

# Actual script to start can be overridden from `docker run`
CMD ["process.json"]
```

`process.json` file in the `CMD` is [described here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)